# javascript to zepto - Uncaught ReferenceError: setColor is not defined

Tags: javascript, zepto

I am converting a javascript plugin to zepto. I have this small function called setColor which runs on page ready event using zepto. This function runs on onclick event. When clicked, it throws me undefined function error.

```
<a href="#" class="colorPicker" onclick="setColor('rgb(68,68,68)');return false;" >
        <img src="images/White.png" class="paint-bucket" />
    </a>
<script>

Zepto(function($){
var colorL;
            function setColor(col)
            {
                colorL = context.strokeStyle = col;
            }
});
</script>
```

P.S = Above code is just a part of my plugin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setColor` function is defined in closure of anonymous function that you provided as argument to `Zepto` and is invisible in global scope. From the other hand `setColor` that you are calling as `onclick` handler should be defined in global scope (which is `window`). In order to make your `setColor` function accessible from anywhere you should define it in the namespace of `window`:

**JavaScript**

```
Zepto(function($){
    var colorL;
    window.setColor = function setColor(col)
    {
        colorL = context.strokeStyle = col;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, thats worked  :). I got an alternative solution for this. Instead of calling the setColor function in HTML onlclick, i made a simple jquery onclick function and gave class names to the buttons.